# Octopress lost commits from source branch

Tags: git, github, octopress

I have my blog on octopress blog engine.

I updated my blog sometime back but back then I committed my changes locally then I did `rake gen_deploy` which published my changes online, after that I lost my complete for my blog.

Current state: I have my changes pushed to master, but I don't have the blog entries in my source branch on github. Since I forgot to push my local commits from source branch.

Recently I wrote another blog post which I committed and tried pushing it.

It says my source branch is not up-to-date with origin/source.

How can I solve this problem?

I don't have commits from my old repository which I lost although they exist in master branch as a result of `rake gen_deploy`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

It will update your local git file system with the content form the server.
If you see that your current branch has update then pull it.

Comment: The problem is I have my master up to date with remote master, my source branch is also up to date but how can I fetch the lost commits which exits in master as a result of my lost commits from source branch. AFAIK running your suggested command will update all my branched with remote branches. I won't help in getting lost source branch commits.

Comment: First of all checkout the remote master to a new branch and compare it to your local branch. the comparison will reveal any deleted files or modified content. Then you can use `git bisect` to find when did the problem started

Answer (score 0):

`git reflog` will solve this issue. Check the heads one by one using `git log Head@{Id}`. If you find the commits which you want then give `git reset Head@{Id which has the required commits}`

For example: If there are 10 head and the commits which I want is in the 5th head then, the cmd will be `git reset Head@{5}`

This step, believe me, recovered my **63** lost commits.